# How to fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Hero is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I am an Italian guy who is learning javascript..
I am following a course to create a text based RPG but I am stucked with this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Hero is not defined

Where Hero is a class that extends a main class.

It's a localhost project with 2 .js file and one html that link them togheter

**THIS IS IN THE FILE WHERE I CREATE THE STORY**

```
const eroePrincipale = new Hero (nome, 10, sesso, razza, ruoloPersonaggio);
console.log(eroePrincipale);
```

**THIS IS IN THE FILE WHERE I CREATE CHARACTERS**

```
class PersonaggioBase {
constructor(nome, salute){
    this.nome = nome;
    this.saluteMax = salute;
    this.saluteCorrente = salute;
    this.attributi = {
        attacco: 10,
        furtività: 10,
        persuasione: 10
    };
    this.abilità = {
        attacco: 0,
        furtività: 0,
        persuasione: 0
    };
  };
};

class Hero extends PersonaggioBase {
constructor(nome, salute, sesso, razza, ruolo){
    super(nome, salute);
    this.sesso = sesso;
    this.razza = razza;
    this.ruoloPersonaggio = ruolo;
    this.immobilizzato = false;
    this.armaEquipaggiata = {
        nome : 'Nessuna',
        dannoMinimo: null,
        dannoMassimo: null
    };
    this.armaturaEquipaggiata = {
        nome: 'Nessuna',
        attributiBonus: null
    };
  };
};
```

It should log out me the Hero with all the currect stats

Comment: You need to reference the js file that contains the Hero class before the second js file. Can you check if you already do that? It'd be better if you show the html file too.

Comment: How are you linking the files? HTML `<script>` tags? `import`?

Comment: This is the HTML file:
    
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Programmazione%20condivisa/RPG%20BASE/personaggi.js"> </script>
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Programmazione%20condivisa/RPG%20BASE/storia.js"> </script>


"personaggi" means characters
"storia" means story

Answer (score 0):

you have done all right but wrote the function string params wrong.
instead write:

```
const eroePrincipale = new Hero (nome, 10, sesso, razza, ruoloPersonaggio);
```

write

```
const eroePrincipale = new Hero ('nome', 10, 'sesso', 'razza', 'ruoloPersonaggio');
```

Comment: He is getting an error saying "The class Hero is not defined". Thus it's not a parameter type error. If it was, the class would have been initialized without a problem but the inner properties would have been undefined.

Comment: partially right. if you press nome instead of "nome" than you get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: nome is not defined" and the creation will stop with exception

Comment: Oh you are right, it would throw an exception in plain javascript. But it won't on node.js. I mainly work on node.js and thought the plain javascript will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try exporting the class Hero and importing it on the js file that insantiates the class?

To export a class simply add this line to the end of your `personaggi.js` file:

```
export Hero;
```

And add this line at the top of your `storia.js` file:

```
import {Hero} from '/personaggi.js';
```